# Filezilla transfer file name colon replace

Tags: linux, ftp, filesystems, file-server

I have transferred a massive amount of files by filezilla. But a few scattered files are pending being transferred. They had failed since my filezilla server is on windows and filezilla client is on linux and I cannot upload files on windows if their name includes colon `:` as it is illegal on windows.

How can I tell filezilla to upload those files in queue with another name e.g. replacing colon by dash etc. ?

I do not want to stop filezilla or solve the problem on my linux. I want to solve it from filezilla only.

Answer (score 0):

replace the : in your linux client and after make upload, for example you can use sed with find, for example:
`cd /dir_with_many_files && find . -type f -name '*:*' -exec sh -c 'mv '{}' $(echo '{}' | sed 's/:/_/g')' \;`

after that, you can upload the files to your windows server.